# Access PHP Array item value

Tags: php

I have the following script that divides the total by the number of people and stores the results in an array.

Instead of dumping the `$result` array at the end, I wonder if I could echo out the value of each array item in the for loop as it goes?

```
// initial conditions
$total = 1001;
$people = 5;

// count what is the minimal value, that all the results will have
$value = floor($total / $people);
$result = array_fill(0, $people, $value);

// distribute missing "+1"s as needed in the result
$overheads = $total - $value * $people;
for ($i = 0; $i < $overheads; $i++) {
    $result[$i]++;
}

// voila...
var_dump($result);
```

So, the above script *should* loop out:

```
200
200
200
200
201
```

Comment: `foreach ($result as $r) echo $r . "\n";` ?

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i < $overheads; $i++) {
        $result[$i]++;
        echo $result[$i].'\n';
    }

or am I getting the question wrong?

Comment: this.lau_ - you should add as an Answer - that worked great! :)

Comment: You have the solution done in your example......

Comment: Take a look at the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/). The [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) statement is what you need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, you can't *"echo out  the value of each array item
in the for  loop **as it goes**"* because you're  not filling the arrays
in a loop,  you're filling with `array_fill()`. The loop  you have is to
work  with the  remainder. If  you echo  out there,  you'll get  partial
results. So either  you keep your code  and echo the values  at the end,
with a simple line:

```
foreach ($result as $r) echo "$r\n";
```

Or you  modify your  code to  fill the arrays  in another  manner. Which
might  be interesting.  Note that  you're forgetting  about the  modulus
operator, `%`, for the remainder of division. This line:

```
$overheads = $total - $value * $people;
```

Could be written simply as:

```
$overheads = $total % $people;
```

An idea to fill in a loop:

```
// initial conditions
$total = 1001;
$people = 5;

$value = floor($total/$people);
$overheads = $total % $people;

foreach (range(1, $people) as $p) {
    $r = $value;
    if ($overheads) {
        # if there is still remainders:
        $r++;
        $overheads--;
    }
    # echo the value and also store it
    echo "$r\n";
    $result[] = $r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// initial conditions
$total = 1001;
$people = 5;

// count what is the minimal value, that all the results will have
$value = floor($total / $people);
$result = array_fill(0, $people, $value);

// distribute missing "+1"s as needed in the result
$overheads = $total - $value * $people;

$i = 1;
foreach($result as $res)
{

    if ($i < $people){
     echo $res . "\n";
    }else{
        echo $res + 1 . "\n";
    }
   $i++;
}
```

// voila...